# Receiving an error in our ERP system that a column does not belong to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Infor's Cloudsuite ERP system and have a dataview where the results of that dataview are derived from a stored procedure.   I have this question tagged under SQL Server because I believe the problem lies there and not in the ERP, although I am not 100% sure about that either.  Also, I can't add the Infor tag and Cloudsuite tag because I need a reputation of 1,500 or more on here.

When I launch the dataview, I get the following:

[image]

When I execute the stored procedure inside SQL Server it runs fine.

Here is the final select statement at the end of the Stored Procedure.

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
    CoNum CoNum        
    ,CoLine    CoLine              
    ,Job           Job
    ,Suffix        Suffix
    ,SalesComplete       SalesComplete       
    ,EngineeringComplete        EngineeringComplete
    ,NDEComplete                NDEComplete
    ,QAReviewComplete           QAReviewComplete
    ,CustomerSubAppComplete     CustomerSubAppComplete
    ,FinalReviewComplete       FinalReviewComplete
    ,Notes                      Notes
    ,OrderLineStatus            OrderLineStatus
    ,JobSuffixStatus            JobSuffixStatus
    ,OrderLineDueDate           OrderLineDueDate
    ,CustomerOrderDate      CustomerOrderDate
    ,CustomerName        CustomerName
FROM #orderProcessing
```

Any help would be appreciated.  At this point I am stumped.

Comment: Can you post the full query as the error is talking about a table called CACOrderProcessingReport but the query is pulling from a temp table

Comment: Correct.  In Cloudsuite you do what is called extending a dataview.  So the IDO is called CACOrderProcessingReport but it extends the SLDataViewsReport IDO.  To the system the table looks like CACOrderProcessingReport even though the stored procedure is returning a temp table.